# /etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default not executed

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gdm, logout

I used to have a session clean up the script in lightdm (unity).
Now with **ubuntu 18.04**, I am moving this script to `/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default`.

However, the **script** is **never executed**.

For curiosity, I tried the `/etc/gdm3/PreSession/Default` - which is executed, but this does not solve my problem.

Any idea how I can make sure that the `/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default` script is executed?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where I found your question while I searched for answers.  I never found and answer, but I did discover a resolution that worked.

I had prevously made manual changes to the password and shadow files rather than using the tools such as `usermod` and `passwd`.

There are other files that are associated with the account that affect the integrity of the user's configuration.

I fixed the user's configuration by backing up the home directory (saving it by a different name).  Then creating a temporary home directory by the user's name.

Then I use the account tools to remove the user and his home directory.  Then I created the user again.  Then I restored the user's home directory.  After that the `/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default` script executed.

**These are the commands:**

```
$ cd /home
$ sudo mv ~user user.bak
$ sudo mkdir ~user
$ sudo deluser --remove-home user
$ sudo adduser user
$ sudo mv ~user ~user.del
$ sudo mv ~user.bak user
```

**Note:**
Replace name `user` with the name of the userID you're having problems with.
You can also delete the `user.del` directory when you finish.